# React native project can't start

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, react-native, npm

```
node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:446
      throw err;
      ^

Error: Cannot find module 'C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_npx\7930a8670f922cdb\node_modules\@babel\parser\lib\index.js'. Please verify that the package.json has a valid "main" entry
    at tryPackage (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:438:19)
    at Module._findPath (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:687:18)
    at Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1056:27)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:923:27)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1137:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/helpers:121:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_npx\7930a8670f922cdb\node_modules\metro\src\Bundler\util.js:14:17)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1255:14)
    at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1309:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1113:32) {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  path: 'C:\\Users\\Admin\\AppData\\Local\\npm-cache\\_npx\\7930a8670f922cdb\\node_modules\\@babel\\parser\\package.json',
  requestPath: '@babel/parser'

}
```

Node.js v20.2.0

When I enter command npx react-native run-android this error has been occurred. So I tried may of ways. but could not success. please help me to solve this issue.

Comment: Looks like a missing dependency issue - try installing it again - `npm i @babel/parser`. If that doesn't work, clear npm cache and reinstall dependencies again

Comment: Can you show us your package.json to make sure, that it has a valid "main" entry?

Answer (score 0):

Try this one :

```
npm run android
```